# Get Inner HTML of Multiple Elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the content of multiple Spans. Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/4XumV/

It's supposed to give me "111, 222, 333, 444". It gives me "undefined" instead.

What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Please include the relevant code within your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you weren't actually getting the `innerHTML` property, you were getting an undefined `html` property. Change it to `innerHTML` and it will work.

http://jsfiddle.net/4XumV/1/

Comment: @Bayu no problem. You might also consider replacing `$("#main")` with `document.getElementById("main")` -- it will perform much better.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
$(function()
{
    var allLatestNews = $("#main").find('span');
    $.each(allLatestNews, function(i,val){
        alert($(val).text());
    });
});
```

I was wondering WHY your code wasn't working and JQuery does return an array of elements from the selector, this could have also worked:

```
for(var i = 0; i < allLatestNews.length; i++)
{
    alert($(allLatestNews[i]).text());
}
```

First wrap the element as a JQuery object and then querying `text()` not html, which is accessed by a function not a property.

Your updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4XumV/9/

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing jquery's `html` with `innerHTML`.

You can either use `innerHTML`:

http://jsfiddle.net/4XumV/3/

```
alert(allLatestNews[i].innerHTML);
```

or jquery's `html`:

http://jsfiddle.net/4XumV/5/

```
alert(allLatestNews.eq(i).html());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this it should work

```
     allLatestNews.each(function()
     {
      alert($(this).html());
     });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $elms = $('#main').find('span');
$elms.each(function(){ alert($(this).text()); });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4XumV/2/

Answer (score 0):

This is working

```
var allLatestNews = $("#main").find('span');

    $.each(allLatestNews ,function( index , value){
    console.log($(value).html());
    });
```

instead of `console.log($(value).html());` you can write `alert($(value).html());`

Answer (score 0):

The property of a DOM element to return the inner HTML is named `innerHTML` not `html`

```js
allLatestNews[i].innerHTML
```

Or using jQuery

```js
$(allLatestNews[i]).html()
```

[Updated JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4XumV/8/)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
    var allLatestNews = $(this).find("#main span");

    for(var i = 0; i < allLatestNews.length; i++)
    {
        alert(allLatestNews[i].innerHTML);
    }
```